# Android and Rust, OpenSSL cross-compilation fails to link on ARM V7

Tags: android, c++, rust, openssl

I have a Rust project which depends on openSSL. I managed to compile this project for Android (as in, compilation succeeds and a static library .a is generated).

However, when I try to compile the Android APK, I get the following error:

```
C/C++: ld: error: relocation R_ARM_REL32 cannot be used against symbol 'OPENSSL_armcap_P'; recompile with -fPIC
C/C++: >>> defined in ../../../../jniLibs/armeabi-v7a/libengine.a(libcrypto-lib-armcap.o)
C/C++: >>> referenced by libcrypto-lib-armv4-mont.o:(.text+0x0) in archive ../../../../jniLibs/armeabi-v7a/libengine.a
```

- I've resorted to adding the following dependency to my `cargo.toml`: `openssl = { version = "*", features = ["vendored"] }`
- The armv8 compilation succeeds and the app can be launched (from Android Studio which only build one arch). However, the compilation for armv7 fails when trying to generate an APK.
- I have already tried recompiling with the `fPIC` flag to no success, the same error pops up
- Some research shows this might be an issue with OpenSSL itself: [same issue in Python](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/22414) and [the source changes to OpenSSL itself](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/pull/22181). However I don't know how to apply this changes to my Rust compilation process.
- [Exact issue](https://github.com/android/ndk/issues/191) on the NDK repo itself, which has been closed.

Any idea how can I correctly cross-compile OpenSLL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the problem was with the sources of OpenSSL itself. This might be fixed in the future but the only option I had was to compile OpenSSL with a patch.

The gist with the script I used to compile and patch the sources [is here](https://gist.github.com/ospfranco/7b691ddc8f2fdba66dde5f67564a7c69).

Answer (score 0):

From a portability perspective, rustls is easier. There is no need to ensure that the OpenSSL library is installed on the target machine, cross-compiling is also better

Comment: Unfortunately, OpenSSL is not a direct dependency, I cannot swap it. As for cross-compilation, I also tried with the openssl-sys crate (with the vendored option) and the same error still pops up.